# How do you capture the response text for an ajax:success event handler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, prototypejs

I am probably missing something obvious, but I'm new to Prototype, coming from jQuery. I have a link created using link_to and remote=>true that output an AJAX link that is working.

Here is the JS I have:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
    $$('.checkoff-link').each(function(element) {
        element.observe('ajax:success', successfulCheckOff);
    });
});

// when they tick it off, check it off
function successfulCheckOff(e) {
    // shrink and strike out the text
    var element = e.element();
    var label = $(getLabelIdFromLinkId(element.id));

    label.addClassName('strikeout');
}
```

How do I get the responseText of the ajax request? I'm trying to pass data back from my controller on success, and I don't know how to capture it in the JS tier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out using this handy tutorial:
https://github.com/rails/prototype-ujs

Essentially, all of the response information is stored in event.memo, so you can use code like this:

```
var response = e.memo;
```

To then access everything you need.

And you can get the HTML/Text/JSON from the response using the responseText method:

```
var html_return = e.memo.responseText;
```